# Split dataframe multivalue columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pipe delimited file with data as:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5
row1|r1|src1#src2|val1#val2|val4#val5
row2|r2|src2#src1|val11#val12|val14#val15
row3|r3|src1#src2|val44|val23#val33
```

`col3`, `col4` and `col5` are multi value fields with # as a separator. Now based on the `src2` position in `col3`, I need to consider the value in `col4` and `col5` for the same position. For example if `src2` is in second position, then take only values from `col4` and `col5` which are at second position as below:

Output :

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5
row1|r1|src2|val2|val5
row2|r2|src2|val11|val14
row3|r3|src2||val33
```

I have written this code, but i am not getting the desired result with this:

```
df2 = (df["col3"].str.split("#", expand=True))
df2.loc[df2[0] == 'src2', 'Position'] = '0'

df2.loc[df2[1] == 'src2', 'Position'] = '1'

df.loc[df2['Position']=='0' ,'col4'] = df["col4"].str.split("#", expand=True)[0]

print(df['col4'])
```

Comment: you can maximize the chance of getting an answer by providing [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have uneven "sub-list" length, this is not directly achievable with `explode`.

Here is an approach using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) and `apply`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

cols = ['col3', 'col4', 'col5']

df2 = df.copy()

df2[cols] = (df2[cols]
             .apply(lambda c: c.str.split('#'))
             .apply(lambda r: next(filter(lambda x: x[0]=='src2',
                                          zip_longest(*r)), float('nan')),
                            axis=1, result_type='expand')
            )
```

output:

```
   col1 col2  col3   col4   col5
0  row1   r1  src2   val2   val5
1  row2   r2  src2  val11  val14
2  row3   r3  src2   None  val33
```